# FireFox "not well formed" jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, firefox

I am getting warnings in firefox, "not well formed", when converting an XML doc into a jQUery object.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<general>
    <temperature>
        <myTemp val = "10"/>
    </temperature>
</general>
```

**JS**

```
var xml = $.get('path/to/my.xml');
var myObject = {
   temperature : $(xml).find('myTemp').attr('val')
}
```

Firefox error is like

```
x not well-formed <unknown>:1:75
```

And I don't get the error if I comment out only myObject declaration, so it's not the XML file.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I am seeing the same issue and I'm not having much luck hunting around the internet!

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't have a space in your attribute declaration; e.g., `val="10"`, not `val = "10"` - but that's not what's causing the error.

Second, `$.get('path/to/my.xml')` returns a promise, not a string.  The "not well-formed" error is coming from trying to parse "[object Object]" as XML.

What you want is:

```
$.get('path/to/my.xml').done(function (xml) {
    var myObject = {
       temperature : $(xml).find('myTemp').attr('val')
    }
});
```